# Customize swagger schema for a nested type using swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, enumeration, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an api (ASP.NET Core 3.0) that allows users to search a document database using various query parameters to filter and order the results. One of the parameters is an `Order` parameter that defines how to order the results. The acceptable values are limited to the values of an enum.

I now need to add more behavior to the enum, so I re-wrote it as an [Enumeration Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) so that I can add object-oriented behavior to it. The problem I now have is that Swashbuckle flattens out the properties of the Enumeration rather than leaving it as a single parameter. Here are my enumeration and parameter classes:

```cs
// Enumeration
public class DocSearchOrder : Enumeration {
    public static readonly DocSearchOrder DocType = new DocSearchOrder(2, nameof(DocType));
    public static readonly DocSearchOrder DocTypeDesc = new DocSearchOrder(3, nameof(DocTypeDesc));
    public static readonly DocSearchOrder DocDate = new DocSearchOrder(4, nameof(DocDate));
    public static readonly DocSearchOrder DocDateDesc = new DocSearchOrder(5, nameof(DocDateDesc));

    public DocSearchOrder(int value, string name) : base(value, name) {
    }
}

// Search Parameters
public class DocSearchParameters {

    public DocSearchOrder? Order { get; set; }

    // Lots of other search parameters
}
```

Then the method that uses it:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromQuery] DocSearchParameters searchParams) {
    // Do the search
}
```

Swashbuckle flattens `searchParams.Order` into `DocSearchOrder.Id` and `DocSearchOrder.Name`.
The behavior I want to achieve is for my Swagger UI to continue to show a dropdown of the available values (`DocSearchOrder.Name`) that a user can select from with the parameter named "Order". You then pass one of those string values and a custom model binder converts the string to the Enumeration class instance.

I've tried writing a custom `IOperationFilter` but that only seems to work for modifying the schema of types passed to the `GetAsync` method, I can't intercept the schema generation for `searchParams.Order`. I thought what I'd be able to do is somehow intercept the schema generation for any property that is an `Enumeration` and generate an enum schema for it instead of an object schema, but I don't know how to intercept it.

So my question is: is there a way to customize the schema generation for a nested type? Or is there another way to go about this and I'm doing it all wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a regular enum:

```
    public enum DocSearchOrder
    {
        DocType = 2,
        DocTypeDesc = 3,
        DocDate = 4,
        DocDateDesc = 5
    }
```

I think that would that be easier, and there should not give you much trouble
Here is an example from one of mine:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=TestEnum#/TestEnum/TestEnum_Get

Comment: Yes, a regular enum is what I'm currently using. I was wanting to switch to using the Enumeration class so I could add some additional functionality to the "enum" members without relying on a bunch of if..else or switch statements